# HTML injection in parts of email

Tags: html, kotlin, email

I have been searching for a solution for a following problem:
I need to send confirmation of thread created by customer to his email.
Form is made of subject, body, email, name.
I have a template for email which is filled with user's info and then sent to him.

```
val template = "\<p>Hello $contact.name, we confirm that we received your request: $contact.body\</p>"
```

And then add to the template message of his request. Problem is that he can inject HTML in every variable like his name so that the template could look like that:

```
val template = <p> Hello \<button>Click me to be hacked\</button>, we confirm that we received your request\</p>
```

Then I just send confirmation mail to the email filled in form

```
mail.sendMail(email, subject, body)
```

Is is possible to prevent from html injection globally or I need to think about it every time I add some inputs to the page? I tried to do the escapeHtml method inside sending mail but it also escapes the default part like

Hello, we received your request

.

Comment: This can be easily done by using a regular expression to strip the user entry of all html tags. Just search for 'regex strip html tags' - depends on your setup if you want to use js, php or something else, but the method is always the same.

Comment: Aso: NEVER allow user input without validating it first ANYWHERE in your project. It's a major attack vector and will be used at some point by someone.

Comment: @rx2347 yes, but user input is split among my input with html tags <p>user input with html tags</p>

Comment: thats not a problem, you just have to handle your own content different from the user input by validating and stripping user input from tags before you allow it into your <p> tags.